# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code XCODE 15

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, macos-sonoma

I am working on an IOS game made in unity, trying to build and run in XCODE but i keep encountering the error in my title. xcode returns some error lines that I havent been able to properly address.

`
Showing Recent Messages
Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.ToolchainNotFoundException: IL2CPP C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Mac, you must have Xcode installed.

Building for Apple Silicon requires Xcode 9.4 and Mac 10.12 SDK.

Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.

It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.

`

`
Showing Recent Messages
Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!

at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.GetCompatibleXcodeInstallation(Architecture architecture, Version xcodeMinVersion, Version platformSdkMinVersion, Identifier platformSdkIdentifier, XcodePlatformSdk& compatiblePlatformSdk, XcodeInstallation& compatibleXcodeInstallation)

at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.UserAvailableToolchainFor(Architecture architecture, NPath toolChainPath, NPath sysRootPath)

at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.IL2CPPExeCompileCppBuildProgram.BuildProgram.Main(String[] args, String currentDirectory)

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.InProcessBuildProgram.StartImpl(String workingDirectory, String[] arguments) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/InProcessBuildProgram.cs:line 51

`

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` in a terminal to verify the command line tools are installed or to install them.

Comment: I have them installed, is there a line I should run to utilize them?

Comment: Does `xcode-select -p` print a valid path? How about `xcodebuild -version`?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer  and Xcode 15.0.1
Build version 15A507 respectively.

Answer (score -1):

So, my solution was actually occurring on the Unity side. I had version 2022.3.4f1. I downloaded 2022.3.11 and somehow eveything started working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).